Voice controlled stopwatch
I'm looking for an Android stopwatch app that I can control with my voice: I say "go" and it starts timing, I say "stop" and it stops, recording the time.
I don't want to enable any overarching AI voice assistant because of concerns about privacy, so I'm really just looking for a stopwatch app with this kind of voice control built in. Does it exist?
